# Primefaces dataExporter to xls Float number becomes text in spreadsheet cell

Tags: excel, primefaces, numbers, data-export

Environment:

- jsf 2.2
- primefaces 6.1
- wilfly 10

I'm trying to export a dataTable to an excel with dataExporter from primefaces, but I'm firstly getting

```
<p:commandButton id="btnExpExcel"
                 alt="#{msgs.inv_exportinvoices}"
                 ajax="false">
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="lstFactures" 
                    fileName="invoices"/>
</p:commandButton>
<p:dataTable id="lstFactures" var="inv"
...
```

**Option 1** I get in xls pex. 83.2 but we use , as decimal instead of .

```
...
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.total}">
    <h:outputText value="#{inv.total}">
        <f:convertNumber locale="#{localeBean.locale}"/>
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
...
```

**Option 2** I get in xls pex. 83,2 but excel deal with that as text instead of number

```
...
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.total}">
    <h:outputText value="#{inv.total}" />
</p:column>
...
```

**Option3 ** with

public void postProcessXLS(Object document) {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow header;

```
    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GREEN.index);
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    int ind = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < invoices.size() + 1; row++) {
        header = sheet.getRow(row);
        for (int col = 0; col < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); col++) {
            ...
                }
                if (col == 5) {
                    HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(col);
                    //Total is a float
                    cell.setCellValue(invoices.get(ind).getTotal());
                    ind++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to exportFuction="#{inv.total}" but I got some kind of error exportFunction="#{inv.total}": Method not found...

What I'm getting in xls is the following

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dataexporter export datatable columns' number as integer or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243263/dataexporter-export-datatable-columns-number-as-integer-or-double)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the fields in p:dataTable are exported as text.
If you want to convert a value in a different format, you have to implement a postProcessor method.

Example:
page.xhtml

```
<p:dataExporter type="xls" target="lstFactures" fileName="invoices" postProcessor="#{bean.ppMethod}" />
```

Class Bean

```
public void ppMethod(Object document) {   
    Workbook workbook = (Workbook) document;
    ...
    CellStyle totalCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle(); 

    totalCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#,##0.00"));

    Cell currentCell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0);


    currentCell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(currentCell.getStringCellValue()));
    currentCell.setCellStyle(defaultCellStyle);
    ...
}
```

Comment: .. and how do you get the `workbook` in the post process method?

Comment: By casting the Object parameter of the post processor method. By definition, the post processor method has an Object parameter. I edited the answer to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I guess that you should to change the method to improve what he want, some like loop for in the workbook.